# JavaScript/JQuery function doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My function in JavaScript/JQuery doesn't return anything; I want it to return the result for me but it won't. As you can see, the return is the `$("#resultado").html("O Valor do produto ficara "+resultado);` but this doesn't appear as it should when the function is run:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#target").submit(function(){

    var preco_dolar = $("#preco_dolar").val(); 
    var dolar = $("#dolar").val();
    var frete = $("#frete").val();


    if ($('#drop').is(':checked'))
    {
    var drop = 5.8;
    }else var drop = 0; 


    if(typeof preco_dolar == "undefined"){
        alert("Erro ! Falta preco do produto");
    }

    if(typeof frete == "undefined"){
        var frete = 40;
    }

    if(typeof dolar == "undefined"){
        var dolar = 2.16;
    }




    var resultado = (preco_dolar*dolar)+frete;

    $("#resultado").html("O Valor do produto ficara "+resultado);




});
</script>
```

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to wrap your script into

```
// here $("#target") is nothing

$(document).ready(function () {
    // here $("target") exists
});
```

Second for your improvement, don't use

```
if(typeof dolar == "undefined"){
    dolar = 2.16;
}
```

Use instead

```
if(!dolar){
    dolar = 2.16;
}
```

That is the same as you would do:

```
if(!dolar && dolar == 0 && dolar == "" && dolar == false && dolar == undefined){
    dolar = 2.16;
}
```

To make 0 a valid value, use

```
if (!dolar && dolar !== 0) {
    dolar = 2.16;
}
```

Also don't use `var dolar = 0;` twice. If you declared it already, simply use `dolar =`, to not overwrite the already declared var.

Comment: *1.* You only have to wrap the script if it appears before the form is rendered on the page. *2.* What if `dolar` is zero? You just reset it! typeof checks are not bad, would probably be better as just `if (dolar === undefined) {`

Comment: @epascarello yeah you're right because of 0 being a valid value. he actually declares jquery script tag right before his script, so it's predictable the element doesn't exist already.

Comment: Probably even easier to just do `var dolar = $("#dolar").val() || 2.16;` As long as val() returns a string. :)

Comment: @epascarello hah expanding your tricks: `var dolar = +$("#dolar").val() || 2.16` makes sure you have a number. but we are losing now the valid 0 so an if check will be required.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the form submission so the page is refreshing and resetting the page. Use [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to stop the form submission.

```
$("#target").submit(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return false;
```

should suffice.

alternatively, you could prevent the default behavior by

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `return` statement. Javascript functions require a return statement to return a value:

```
function test() {
    return 5;
}
```

Comment: The question sounds like this is what the OP was referring too, but that is not the case.